# Finding the width of a set of text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out if there is a way to figure out if a set of text is wider then the cell it is occupied in. All what I found is to use text wrap and auto-fit options.

What I am working on is a template that would auto fill in with a macro - getting the information from a database. I want to be able to figure out if the text in certain cells is too long, then the marco will truncate the text and add it another cell in the row below. Using auto-height options will mess up the template structure so I want to avoid it by all means.

So in summary, I want to be able to obtain how wide is certain set of text.

Using Excel 2016

Comment: Since Excel uses a rough estimate of characters as their column width, compare Len(String) to column.width.

Comment: If possible, I'd also recommend using a monospaced font, like Consolas, for this.  That way the length of a string will have a direct impact on the total width of the text.

Comment: I will see how consistent of results I get with Len(string). As for using a monospaced font - our template has to be in Arial and there is no flexibility in that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a kludge using VBA:

```
Dim myWidth As Double
Dim textWidth As Double

myWidth = Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
Range("A1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
textWidth = Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
Range("A1").ColumnWidth = myWidth
MsgBox textWidth
```

Note that this will give you different results, depending on the font in the target cell

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea. I will give it a shot and try to do it an background sheet that hidden to the user so that I am not messing with the template and set of images in it.